# How do I correct these "Expected Expression Before 'Stack'" and "Not Enough Arguments to Function 'Push'" errors?

Tags: c, string, stack, delimiter, state-machine

This is my first question ever asked on this site.  The program I'm working on is supposed to check a string to make sure that all delimiters found within the string match up ('(' and ')', '[' and ']', and so on).  While I'm rather certain it won't work right away once these errors get corrected, I'd like to at least be able to run the flawed program and go from there.

What I believe to be the relevant segments of code are located in the following section of my finite state machine subprogram, and my push and pop subprograms:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include "boolean.h"



typedef struct stacknode {

      char data;

      struct stacknode *next;

} *stack;


char fms(stack *, char); /*Prototypes for relevant subprograms*/


char fms(stack *s, char input){

   int state = 0;

   char i = -1, o, c;

   while(1) {

      switch(state) {

         case '0': i = i++;

                   if (isopen(input))

                      state = 1;

                   else {

                      if (isclose(input))

                         state = 2;

                      else {

                         if (input == '\0')

                            state = 3;

                         else

                            state = 4;

                      }

                   }

            break;

         case '1': push(stack *s, o); /*Two errors here. "Expected expression before 'Stack', and "Not enough arguments to function 'Push'".*/

                   state = 0;

            break;

         case '2': if(!is_empty) {

                      c = input;

                      o = pop(&stack *s); /*One error here. "Expected expression before 'Stack'".*/

                      if(!isbrother(o, c)) {

                         printf("Error: Pair does not match.");

                         return FALSE;

                      }

                   }

                   else {

                      printf("Error: Too many closing delimiters.");

                      return FALSE;

                   }

                   state = 0;
```

Please remember I decided to only show the part of my fms subprogram relevant to my errors.  It's quite lengthy otherwise.

```
void push(stack *s, char o) {

   stack temp;



   temp = (stack) malloc(sizeof(struct stacknode));

   temp->data = o;

   temp->next = (*s);

   (*s) = temp;

}



char pop(stack *s) {

   stack temp;

   char data_popped;



   temp = *s;

   data_popped = temp->data;

   *s = temp->next;

   free (temp);

   return data_popped;

}
```

Any help you all can graciously give me will be greatly appreciated.  I should be able to figure out the rest once these errors are disposed of.

Answer (score 1):

`case '1': push(stack *s, o);` you should call functions with passing arguments (such as pass by value or reference) without data types.

You just need to pass the variable as,

```
push(s, o); //Where s holds the base address
```

Comment: There is no "*pass by reference*" in C. However passing a pointer could be seen as passing a reference, but still the address the pointer specifies, holds is passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do:

```
push(stack *s, o)
```

do

```
push(s, o)
```

as you do not need to declare the type of variables when calling functions, only when declaring the function itself.